# httptest.ResponseRecorder has no field or method Result

Tags: unit-testing, go

So this one is really weird, I'm trying to get a mock response that renders JSON. My test looks like this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)
...

func TestMessageFromResponse(t *testing.T) {
    mc := MyController{}
    body := "{ \"message\":\"kthxbai\" }"
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    w.Write([]byte(body))
    resp := w.Result()
    msg := mc.messageFromResponse(resp)
    if msg != "kthxbai" {
        t.Errorf("Expected response body to be kthxbai but was %s", msg)
    }
}
```

I'm testing the method `messageFromResponse` on `MyController`but its not even building. When I run `go test` in my project directory, I get the following error:

```
./my_controller_test.go:115: w.Result undefined (type *httptest.ResponseRecorder has no field or method Result)
```

I should also mention that I am successfully using `httptest.ResponseRecorder` as a writer stub elsewhere in this same file, but it's just failing when I try to access `Result()`.

Comment: What version of Go are you using? I see that *httptest.ResponseRecorder does have a Result() method on the official (1.7) godoc, but when I run my local godoc (I still have 1.6 installed currently) I can't find it.
Edit: sure enough, [it's a new feature of Go1.7](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#net_http_httptest)

Comment: If you think you've upgraded to 1.7 already, it's probably still worth trying to clean out the directory where you had Go installed, dropping in a "fresh" Go1.7 directory instead, and then deleting your `pkg` and `bin` directories before trying the test again.

Comment: Huh...nice! I looked for that but I must have missed it. Thanks!

Comment: @JesseAmano If you want to type that up in an answer, I'll accept it for posterity's sake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially addressed this as a comment because I was unsure of relevance, but for posterity:

The online [godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/) always references the latest release. In this case, the `Result()` method was added in Go1.7 which only released last week. When in doubt, check your local godoc by running `godoc -server` or `godoc <packagename>`.